# Yii: nesting lazy loading with eager loading

Tags: php, activerecord, yii, lazy-loading, eager-loading

Sure I'm missing out something or not thinking about a better way to accomplish what I need, but here is what I want to do.

I have three models: `A`, `B` and `C`. `A` has a relation `MANY-MANY` with `B` called `relation1`, and `B`has a relation `MANY-MANY` with `C`, called `relation2`. I want to get all `B` records with their `C` relations (eager loading), but  just from an `A` instance (lazy loading, because I don't want to waste memory loading all `relation1` instances).

So, what I want to do should be something like the following:

```
A::model()->findByPk($somePrimaryKey)->relation1->with('relation2');
```

Of course that's not working because using `relation1` lazy loading I'm getting an array of instances and then I'm tryng to apply the `with()` method to a non-object.

Sure I can do a little bit of work around iterating through the array, but I want to know if there is a quick and elegent way :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
A::model()->findByPk($somePrimaryKey)->with('relation1.relation2');
```

I cant find any sense in that you "don't want to waste memory loading all relation1 instances"

This way you are just loading the B models that relate to that specific A model. not all of them.

Also take a look at [Relational Query with through](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.arr#relational-query-with-through)

Comment: Ok, thank you @Asgaroth. I thought that nesting the two `with` that way I was loading first all records of relation1.